# Nuget restore caches failures and doesn't retry

Tags: msbuild, nuget

Firstly, I'm not sure if it is significant, but I am running into this issue specifically when building my .NET project via MSBuild, not when building locally in IDE, or running nuget CLI commands locally.

First time building a project, the build fails as a result of being unable to find a particular package (in this case, `Csv`), and the following lines appear in the build log:

```
  Restoring packages for PROJECT_NAME
    GET http://SOURCE/FindPackagesById()?id='Csv'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
...
error NU1101: Unable to find package Csv. No packages exist with this id in source(s): ...
```

Subsequent attempts fail for the same reason, but with a slightly different log message (note `CACHE` instead of `GET`):

```
  Restoring packages for PROJECT_NAME
    CACHE http://SOURCE/FindPackagesById()?id='Csv'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
...
error NU1101: Unable to find package Csv. No packages exist with this id in source(s): ...
```

Finally, when the package source is updated and the missing package is made available, the build still fails for the same reason, with the same log message mentioning `CACHE`. I suspect nuget is not actually polling the source, instead just continuing to see the cached failure.

```
  Restoring packages for PROJECT_NAME
    CACHE http://SOURCE/FindPackagesById()?id='Csv'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
...
error NU1101: Unable to find package Csv. No packages exist with this id in source(s): ...
```

I tried adding `<RestoreNoCache>true</RestoreNoCache>` to my csproj but that didn't affect the outcome, I still see the `CACHE` lines in the log and the build still fails, so I suspect this is referring to an unrelated cache.